# Git PowerShell Cmdlets returning git info as objects

Tags: git, powershell

Are there any PowerShell Cmdlets for interfacing with Git? Especially 'git log'. All this regex parsing is numbing by buns.
Maybe with Microsoft's recent interest in Git, someone is working on this using libgit2sharp? I'm aware of posh-git, but I don't think it adds any cmdlets for returning git info as objects.

Comment: I don't know of any, but it should be relatively easy to write your own if you can't find any others. Thanks for the link to libgit2sharp.

Comment: I plan on doing exactly that with Pit ( https://github.com/manojlds/Pit ). Do watch that space and provide your suggestions too :)

Comment: @manojlds that's great. Is any of that functional at the moment?

Comment: I started it as a way to manage git repos. But started extending the functionality. For example `get-content` returns the content of README.

Answer (score 2):

`Pit` ( https://github.com/manojlds/pit ) has some basic support for `git status` and `git log`. Use the `Get-GitStatus` and `Get-GitLog` cmdlets respectively. It is very simple, at very early stages, so would love some suggestions.

Comment: Should Pit work for powershell 5 (or powershell core 6?) it's [not working for me](https://github.com/manojlds/Pit/issues/2).